# WPF webbrowser opens PDF file in Adobe reader window

Tags: wpf, pdf

I am creating one 32bit WPF application.It needs to show created PDF in WebBrowser control.
While doing ,

```
"WebBrowser.Navigate(new Url("D:\\TestPDF\\MyDocument.pdf"))";
```

it opens PDF file in Adobe reader window.

My Need is PDF should be opened inside WebBrowser not in Adobe reader window.
I have also tried `WebBrowser.NavigateToStream` and `WebBrowser.Source` but its not working.

What can be solution for this? I am looking forward for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked, that you have the Adobe reader installed for the Internet Explorer? You should also verify, that your Internet Explorer is allowed to open PDF-Files embedded.

Sometimes it helpes, to use another Internet Explorer Rendering Engine. This can be archived in with the following code (be warned: Administrator rights are needed for that).

```cs
private void CheckAndFixWebBrowserRenderingEngine()
{
    RegistryKey baseRegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
    string renderingEngineSubKeyString = @"SOFTWARE";

    // 64bit operationg systems have another registry path
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    {
        renderingEngineSubKeyString += @"\Wow6432Node";
    }

    renderingEngineSubKeyString += @"\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";

    var assemblyValueKey = Path.GetFileName(App.ResourceAssembly.Location);
    var renderingEngingeValue = 9999; // check other values below

    try
    {
        RegistryKey sk1 = baseRegistryKey.CreateSubKey(renderingEngineSubKeyString);

        var value = sk1.GetValue(assemblyValueKey);
        if (value == null || value.ToString() != renderingEngingeValue.ToString())
        {
            sk1.SetValue(assemblyValueKey, renderingEngingeValue);

            LogHandler.Instance.Add(string.Format("Did update webbrowser rendering engine from {0} to 9000.", value == null ? "[missing]" : value));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHandler.Instance.Add("Could not check webbrowser rendering engine in registry.");
        LogHandler.Instance.Add(ex.ToString(), Logging.LoggingPriorities.Exception);
    }

    /*
    9999 (0x270F) 
    Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

    9000 (0x2328) 
    Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

    8888 (0x22B8) 
    Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

    8000 (0x1F40) 
    Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.

    7000 (0x1B58) 
    Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.
    */
}
```

Comment: I found just a simple thing using inter operable. Add user control (Winform) with adobe reader and put it into wpf using interoperability

Comment: @Bernhard Krenz, this code is valid for 32bit windows, but it's not woking on 64bit versions.