# How to auto allow content for web browser control

Tags: html, wpf, pdf, activex, webbrowser-control

[How to automatically allow blocked content in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038724/how-to-automaticaly-allow-blocked-content-in-ie)

how to make it auto allow active X control

```
<html>
<body>

<object
  classid="clsid:ca8a9780-280d-11cf-a24d-444553540000" id="pdf1" 
  type="application/pdf"
  data="file://02_LAB_LeaveApplication.pdf"
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%">

<param name="src" "value"="file://02_LAB_LeaveApplication.pdf"></param>

</object>

</body>
</html>
```

i change to use web browser control instead of user control, it do not pop up allow, just this

[image]

Comment: To disable the security prompt for Internet Explorer, you'd have to alter the Local Security Zone settings, which is a bad idea. However, back to [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054379/how-to-display-pdf-in-web-browser-control-instead-of-opening-acrobat-reader/18059160#18059160), the prompt doesn't occur when you use this approach with C# WebBrowser control, which has a bit different security model. I posted a link to sample C# project back there, give it a try.

Comment: success to run your project, after move to my big WPF project, it show a red cross