# Awesomium Displaying Adobe Reader plugin outside of browser window

Tags: c#, xaml, awesomium

I've also asked this question on the Awesomium question/answer deal ([here](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/2135/adobe-reader-plugin.html)), but have gotten no reply, so I am asking here hoping that someone here has dealt with the issue. Whenever I render a PDF in an iframe, it shows as a separate app in a window. I don't need it to be displayed in an iframe, or even visible at all, I just need it to launch the print window, so that filled out PDF can be printed... please help... (I am currently using v 1.7.1 of Awesomium, though I had the same problem is a previous 1.6.? version)

Comment: Consider hosting Acrobat Reader ActiveX control directly, side-by-side with Awesomium. It's quite snappy, here's how it can be done:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380019/Using-Adobe-Reader-in-a-WPF-app/ , 

http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/

Comment: If you use this comment as an answer, I will choose yours as the accepted answer and even up-vote it. BTW, the video in the second link is what actually helped me the most...

Comment: Thank you - I've taken this opportunity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider hosting Acrobat Reader ActiveX control directly, side-by-side with Awesomium. It's quite snappy, here's how it can be done:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380019/Using-Adobe-Reader-in-a-WPF-app/
http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/

The Reader Control API is described here:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACReference.pdf

Comment: Click the image in that hugeonion link to get a step by step of doing it... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with `WebBrowser` Control in C# ... that might help you ...

Comment: @ Grant Winney .. I dont know exactly .. but in webbrowser control we can show the details .. so i said.. sorry if it is wrong...

Comment: Reason that I can not use WebBrowser is that it depends on the version of IE that is installed on the user's machine... as I am using some newer technologies to accomplish my goals, that that even IE 8 can not handle, I must resort to something where I can control the version installed...I am open to other browser solutions... that can accommodate these things...

Comment: Besides, using Acrobat Reader plugin inside WebBrowser has its own issues, [particularly, with WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054379/how-to-display-pdf-in-web-browser-control-instead-of-opening-acrobat-reader/).