# Difference in using WindowsFormsHost over WebBrowser to view PDF files?

Tags: wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control, windowsformshost

I'm creating an application that will heavily use PDF file viewing.  Is there a difference/advantage in using WindowsFormsHost over WebBrowser?  WebBrowser is just a line of code versus WindowsFormsHost setup. So, I'm curious if there are any advantages of using WindowsFormsHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF WebBrowser control runs in IE protected mode by default, and Adobe PDF Reader plugin is known to have issues with that. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18054379/1768303). I'd go with `WindowsFormsHost` and host PDF Reader ActiveX directly, [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353725/1768303).

Comment: Is there a way do disable the protected mode to eliminate any potential issues with the plugin?  Could it cause any additional problems?

Comment: You could try disabling the protected mode with WebBrowser [Feature Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982) (I haven't tried that). If you decided to go with hosting PDF Reader ActiveX directly, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18306632/2674222) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, I will try messing with the Feature Control to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: No problem, let us know if you find a combination of features that works reliably.